# Subdivision surface problem and jagged object

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, modifiers, objects

I have just started learning Blender. I need help with subdivision surface. I added a Torus and smoothed it and further tried to use the Subdivision surface tool to make it smoother, but instead of being smoother, the Torus scattered into a jagged object. Since then, whenever I try using subdivision surface, i get the same problem.

Please, how can I stop that from happening?

I had to uninstall and reinstall Blender, but the problem persists.

Below is a screengrab of what happened.
[image]

Please, I have added more screengrabs to better explain the problem. Below is a screengrab of the object before I applied the subdivision surface modifier.[image]

And here's what happens after I add the subdivision surface modifier. Note that this particular image is different from the first one I added yesterday because with this particular image, I created the doughnut icing before trying to add the subdivision surface modifier again:[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thanks @moonboots

Comment: you need to copy paste the URL it will create   ;)

Comment: Thanks @moonboots. The problem is not only limited to the current object. Any object that I try to add a subdivision modifier to, I get the same problem: the object gets disfigured as shown in the attached screengrab. I believe I made some changes that I can't seem to track and undo. This is because, the very first time I tried using subdivision modifier, it worked well. But since then, it has not worked again. Where do I attach the file? The link posted above? I'm a complete newbie, so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: it looks like a bug, have you tried with another version of Blender. For the file, upload, then copy the URL (internet address) it has generated and paste it here

Comment: I have just uninstalled Blender 3.1 that I was using and installed Blender 3.2, but the problem persists. So I installed Blender 3.2 on a friend's computer and the subdivision surface modifier problem is not there at all. I believe the problem has to do with some settings I may have made, but I can't track down and undo those settings.

Comment: it looks more like a bug but I can't tell how you could fix that, I hope someone will

Comment: Here's the link to the uploaded file, please. Thanks. https://pasteall.org/blend/16db0dfe2d2e43a4a5546aec0474545d

Comment: it works fine for me, is it the first time you're using giving a Subdivision Surface modifier to a 3D object? What graphic card do you have? I know there are some problems with the AMD but I can't tell if it comes from that, usually it is fixed with previous driver versions

Comment: My computer doesn't use a graphics cards. The first time I tried subdivision surface, it worked well, but subsequent attempts failed. That's why I think it may be as a result of a settings change I may have made which I cant seem to trace currently.

Comment: @Arrimeh as a workaround, you could try enabling Auto-smooth, as it disables GPU subdivision: https://i.imgur.com/bfDKGms.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady My laptop doesn't even have a graphics card, but if what you suggested can still work nonetheless, I would be glad to try it if I get the steps to follow. I'm a complete newbie trying an animation app for the very first time. Thanks.

Comment: I just enabled auto smooth, but the problem persists

Comment: @Arrimeh you could try restarting your computer or building the doughnut again? Since technically you're still on the base stage of the doughnut, it won't take time to remake. Or maybe copy-paste the items into a new file? Make sure to try to use a new file, though.

Comment: @YousufChaudhry I tried all that but it didn't work. Fortunately, when I unchecked the Subdivision checkbox in Edit>Preferences>Viewport, it solved the problem for me. My problem though is that, I installed Blender on a friend's laptop, with the Subdivision checkbox still checked but it doesn't have that problem.